# Grails / Groovy log4j - Log line numbers, method name and class name

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j

It seems that in Grails or better to say Groovy, it is not possible to set the logging pattern  to log line numbers, method and class names. Or you can but you would receive the line number and method name from Log4j class like:

```
%F:%L -≥ SLF4JLog.java:213
```

I've found an issue related to that which was no considered as Grails related:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9789

So is there any way how to log these information in Grails?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [Grails logging - Is there any existing solution to be able to log the File + Line where the call actually occured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070863/grails-logging-is-there-any-existing-solution-to-be-able-to-log-the-file-lin/)

So, you need to use a custom appender...