# Grails: how to properly log the method name (%M in the pattern layout)?

Tags: grails, logging, configuration

I'm using grails. 
In some groovy classes declared in the src I want to have extensive log, with many details.
I need to have details like the method name and line number for extensive debug session of a critical component. So I use a pattern like that:

```
layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p [%c{3}].%M:%L %m %n')
```

But whatever the way I declare my loggers (@Commons or @Slf4j on top of the class, or direct use a LogFactory), I only end up with some garbage info about the current method/line number.

With @Log4j annotation I got lines like:

```
date DEBUG [my.package.MyClass].call:? my message
```

With @Commons:

```
date DEBUG [my.package.MyClass].debug:128 my debug message  
date INFO  [my.package.MyClass].info:128 my info
```

where the line number is coming from the logger itself

At the same time hibernate logs are formatted the right way and give me meaningful output:

```
11:12:11,767 TRACE [descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor].extract:71 found [62364] as column [TL5_4_0_]
```

where extract:71 is really where the log occured.

So grails (or groovy) is messing around the logging pattern and I'm looking for a way to get the info I need on my logs lines.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070863/grails-logging-is-there-any-existing-solution-to-be-able-to-log-the-file-lin/

Comment: yes, it looks like this is quite close to an answer: grails is disabled about this and I have too use some custom implementation to help it :)