# Enable debug symbols for log4j from gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

My log4j statements are showing `?`s for line numbers.

## What I've tried

Other answers around the web say this happens when you haven't compiled debug information into your classes.  In Ant for example, this would be done with `<javac debug="true" ...`.  Searching for a way to do this in gradle yields only

http://gradle.org/docs/2.3-rc-2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html

> debug - Tells whether to include debugging information in the generated class files. Defaults to true

I verified this by putting `println compileGroovy.options.debug` in my build.gradle and it prints `true`.  I also found http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/compile-groovy-with-debugging-information, which recommended using `tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) { options.debug = true }`, which also did not work.  Finally, I found `compileGroovy.options.debugOptions.debugLevel`, which can have `source`, `lines`, or `vars`.  This is null by default, but setting it to `source,lines` did not give my line information.

## Reproducing

`gradle init --type groovy-library`

Edit src/main/groovy/Library.groovy to have the additional lines:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
@Log4j
class Library {
    boolean someLibraryMethod() {
       log.info "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
       true
    }
}
```

Add 
`compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'` to build.gradle

Add the file src/main/resources/log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
   <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
               <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %c:%L - %m%n" />
       </layout>
   </appender>
   <root>
           <level value="INFO" />
           <appender-ref ref="console" />
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

And finally run `gradle clean test -i` and observe that you see 
`2015-03-30 08:47:31,996 Library:? - XXXXXXXXXXXXX`
Note the `?` in the message.

## Version information

```
$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-02-16 05:09:33 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     586be72bf6e3df1ee7676d1f2a3afd9157341274

Groovy:       2.3.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.8.0_40 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

My question is, of course, how do I get line numbers to show instead of question marks?

Comment: And for those thinking they may be able to get around this by using log4j2 or commons, those aren't able to figure out line numbers either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy includes the line numbers in the class files.  The problem is that groovy calls methods slightly differently than Java which confuses the Log4j code that determines the line number.

In particular, if you change the line

```
log.info "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

to

```
log.error "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", new Exception('test')
```

you can see some reflection methods are called when groovy invokes methods.  The topmost method in the stack trace I generated was `sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)`, which, being a native method, doesn't have a line number.  This is what Log4j is looking at.  Unfortunately, there's no easy was to filter the stacktrace Log4j uses or tell Log4j to look further down the stack.

One possible solution is to turn on static compilation.  If you add `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` to the Library class or method you'll get the correct line number.

Comment: This is it exactly.  Upon more searching, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070863/grails-logging-is-there-any-existing-solution-to-be-able-to-log-the-file-lin which looks down the stack for the right line number, but it seems too messy and fragile to be worth it.  Guess I will settle for not having line numbers.