# How to have Log4J print line numbers from Groovy sources

Tags: groovy, log4j

I'm writing functional tests using Geb and Spock, and building with Maven using GMavenPlus.  How can I configure Log4J to to print the line numbers from my Groovy source files?  This is my current `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-p] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c:%L - %m%n
```

Currently this results in messages that look like

```
[INFO] 2015-07-28 14:13:51,589 Log4jExample:? - Some useful message
```

This can be reproduced in this small example

```java
@Grab(group='log4j', module='log4j', version='1.2.17') 
import org.apache.log4j.*

@groovy.util.logging.Log4j
class Log4jExample {
    static void main(def args) {
        log.level = Level.INFO
        log.removeAllAppenders()
        log.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout("[%-p] %d %c:%L - %m%n")))
        log.info "Some useful message"
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070863/grails-logging-is-there-any-existing-solution-to-be-able-to-log-the-file-lin/

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not compiled with debug information included in class files"? The debug configuration of GMavenPlus is to control the verbosity of the compilation process, it has no effect on the class files. Is the problem that your debug log statements aren't getting logged?

Comment: @keegan, log statements are not printing the line numbers. please find below my log4j properties file                               log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE= org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern= [%-p] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c:%L- %m%n

Comment: This is an issue with Log4J not knowing how to get the line numbers from Groovy. A workaround was mentioned [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100724050702/http://www.kotek.net/projects/log4j-groovy) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070863/grails-logging-is-there-any-existing-solution-to-be-able-to-log-the-file-lin/), but I'm not sure if there's any examples that are up to date.  I'll keep looking/thinking.  It's also worth mentioning that Log4J recommends against printing the line numbers because it's expensive to compute them.

Answer (score 0):

One solutions is to add the @CompileStatic annotation
Your example it would look like

```
@Grab(group='log4j', module='log4j', version='1.2.17') 
import org.apache.log4j.*

@groovy.util.logging.Log4j
@CompileStatic
class Log4jExample {
   static void main(def args) {
      log.level = Level.INFO
      log.removeAllAppenders()
      log.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(new PatternLayout("[%-p] %d %c:%L - %m%n")))
      log.info "Some useful message"
  }
}
```

Note that by using @CompileStatic the Groovy meta object protocol will be bypassed.